# Conditional formatting with data validation + named range from other sheet in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting, gs-vlookup

I'm really struggling with getting my conditional formatting to work. I've seen a couple of posts online plus here around using INDIRECT to reference the desired cell in a different sheet for a custom formula in my conditional format rule, but it's not working. Wondering if someone can review the sheet and see what I am doing wrong.

In my sheet, you will see exactly what I've coded and I've annotated the desired behavior. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1keGEuaxhjoXJl9TrKWgkAyh4ut22pMmfnTsDranksY0/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you miss equal sign and double quotes.

blue formula:

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,{INDIRECT("WarLinesValuesTypes")},2,0)="Defense"
```

red formula:

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,{INDIRECT("WarLinesValuesTypes")},2,0)="Offense"
```

[image: 0]